# Simulating QC using nondeterministic Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models, nondeterminism, quantum-computing, simulation

Is it more efficient to simulate Quantum Computer using a non-deterministic Turing machine?

Would it be more efficient than simulation using a deterministic Turing machine or [probabilistic Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_Turing_machine)?

I am not sure what are the relations between Turing Machine, [Probabilistic TM](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98344/turing-machines-and-ising-model), Non-deterministic TM and [Quantum TM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Turing_machine) and how they will affect the simulation/emulation of a QC.

Comment: Given that both “efficient” and “quantum computer” have a huge number of possible definitions, I'm not sure if this question is meaningful. What do you have in mind?

Comment: @Gilles, any of the possible definitions should be relevant. It's more a conceptual question.